# windows azure performance difference between XS, S and M servers

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

I was trying to calculate the real-world performance difference between the different server types in Azure, considering the difference in pricing between them.

To calculate this, I have tried spinning up 3 virtual machines - one XS, S and M and running SuperPi on each with 32M setting.

Below are the results:

```
XS VM: 0h 37m 12s
Small VM: 0h 34m 12s
Medium VM: 0h 33m 48s
```

In my eyes, these look very minimal especially considering the price difference.  Is this a valid benchmark, or should I be looking at anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be dependent on what you're running, and whether it takes advantage of RAM, multiple cores, bandwidth, etc. An XS is shared-core, and there's no guarantee *how much core* you'll get at any given time. And an XS only offers 5Mbps bandwidth, whereas S, M, L, and XL offer 100MBps per core (and the A6/A7 offer 1000/2000MBps). Small through XL (and A6/A7) have dedicated cores for your VM.

IF your app is RAM-dependent (such as MongoDB), you'll see huge differences in performance as RAM increases.

My guidance is typically to run the *smallest* VM size that supports your app, and scale *out* as needed. This way, in your low-traffic periods, you can scale in to, say, 2 Small (or XS), and your base price is much lower than, say, a pair of L instances.

Comment: As far as I know, SuperPi is CPU-intensive and is used to compare speeds between computers.  The results are extremely minimal between the XS, S and M, and would like to know exactly in more real-terms, considering the virtualisation.

Comment: I think you need to go with the results of your benchmark. With results being nearly identical, it's probably running single core (and you're probably fortunate to be getting the majority of the shared-core with your XS; you simply can't count on that consistently). As I stated in my answer, the only differences are in network bandwidth, core count, and RAM (also # of attached disks and temp disk space, but I don't see that as impacting any benchmarks).